# change animations when touch sprites

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

In the following function I want to change the animation when I touch on the button.
But the game crash and exit. What's wrong with this code ?

```
 bool GameScene::onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch *touch ,cocos2d::Event *event)
{
    Point touchPoint = Director::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(touch->getStartLocationInView());
    touchPoint = blueButton->convertToNodeSpace(touchPoint);

    Rect *blueBottomRect = new Rect(blueButton->getOffsetPosition().x
        , blueButton->getOffsetPosition().y
        , blueButton->getTextureRect().size.width
        , blueButton->getTextureRect().size.height);
    if (blueBottomRect->containsPoint(touchPoint))
    {
        CCLOG("Blue Touched!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

        auto blueBody = Sprite::create("body1.png");
        blueBody->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width / 2 , +220));


        Vector<SpriteFrame*> animFrames;

        animFrames.reserve(7);
        animFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("body1.png", Rect(0, 0, 99, 153)));
        animFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("body2.png", Rect(0, 0, 99, 153)));
        animFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("body3.png", Rect(0, 0, 99, 153)));
        animFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("body4.png", Rect(0, 0, 99, 153)));
        animFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("body5.png", Rect(0, 0, 99, 153)));
        animFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("body6.png", Rect(0, 0, 99, 153)));
        animFrames.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("body7.png", Rect(0, 0, 99, 153)));

        Animation* animation = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames, 0.09f);
        Animate* animate = Animate::create(animation);

        blueBody->runAction(RepeatForever::create(animate));
        this->addChild(blueBody,100);
        redBody->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);


    }

    Point touchPoint2 = Director::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(touch->getStartLocationInView());
    touchPoint2 = redButton->convertToNodeSpace(touchPoint2);

    Rect *redBottomRect = new Rect(redButton->getOffsetPosition().x
        , redButton->getOffsetPosition().y
        , redButton->getTextureRect().size.width
        , redButton->getTextureRect().size.height);
    if (redBottomRect->containsPoint(touchPoint2))
    {
        CCLOG("Red Touched!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

        auto redBody = Sprite::create("RedBody/bodyRed1.png");
        redBody->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width / 2 , +220));


        Vector<SpriteFrame*> animFrames2;

        animFrames2.reserve(7);
        animFrames2.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("RedBody/bodyRed1.png", Rect(0, 0, 99, 153)));
        animFrames2.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("RedBody/bodyRed2.png", Rect(0, 0, 99, 153)));
        animFrames2.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("RedBody/bodyRed3.png", Rect(0, 0, 99, 153)));
        animFrames2.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("RedBody/bodyRed4.png", Rect(0, 0, 99, 153)));
        animFrames2.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("RedBody/bodyRed5.png", Rect(0, 0, 99, 153)));
        animFrames2.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("RedBody/bodyRed6.png", Rect(0, 0, 99, 153)));
        animFrames2.pushBack(SpriteFrame::create("RedBody/bodyRed7.png", Rect(0, 0, 99, 153)));

        Animation* animation2 = Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames2, 0.09f);
        Animate* animate2 = Animate::create(animation2);

        redBody->runAction(RepeatForever::create(animate2));
        this->addChild(redBody,100);
        blueBody->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);


    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please say What's the runtime/error message and happen on which line ?

Comment: In this question's current state, it's going to be difficult to answer. If you could include the error message and the line on which the program is crashing, it'll help answer the question a lot

Comment: @Yann The compiler does not show any warning .When it happens  i add 'blueBody->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);' and ' redBody->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);' .without this line's code works.

Comment: @EmAdpres  The compiler does not show any warning .When it happens i add 'blueBody->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);' and ' redBody->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);' .without this line's code works

Answer (score 0):

In cocos2d you need first to stop all running action of a node in order to be able to remove that node.

So I think you forget to stop the running action and you can fix it as below:

```
redBody->stopAllActions();
redBody->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
```

and

```
blueBody->stopAllActions();
blueBody->removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
```

Hope It helps.